# docker-java equivalent for 'docker exec {container name} touch test.txt'

Tags: docker, docker-java

I am trying to run an exec command on an already running docker container on a remote host using java.

I am successfully able to run the exec command from the CLI of the host machine using

```
docker exec {container-id} touch asd
```

and can run the touch command successfully.

However, when I try to run the same using docker-java, the program doesn't throw any exceptions, but doesn't run the touch command.

```
            var exec = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(containerId)
                    .withCmd("touch asd")
                    .exec();

            var respo = dockerClient
                    .execStartCmd(exec.getId())
                    .exec(new ResultCallback.Adapter<>())
```

Comment: You want `withCmd("touch", "asd")` -- when you run `docker exec ... touch asd`, the shell splits `touch` and `asd` into two separate arguments; when you're writing Java code you need to do that yourself.

Comment: Hmm interesting, looks like it works. Do you know if escaping the space will work? `withCmd("touch\\ asd")`

Comment: No, it certainly won't. Escaping is shell syntax, but _there is no shell here to honor that syntax_. (And even if there _were_ a shell: in this context, backslashes _hold things together_, which is the opposite of what you want: you want them split apart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker exec ... touch asd`, your shell splits `touch` and `asd` into two separate arguments.

Using the Java library, *there is no shell*, so the arguments never get split (causing the system to try to run a program named like `"/usr/bin/touch asd"` *with the space as part of its name* in the container). It's on you to do that splitting yourself:

```java
var exec = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(containerId)
           .withCmd("touch", "asd")
           .exec()
```

...or to explicitly cause a shell to be run inside the container to do it for you:

```java
var exec = dockerClient.execCreateCmd(containerId)
           .withCmd("sh", "-c", "touch asd")
           .exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works as expected with other commands as well. If I may ask one more favor, could you please redirect me to some resources where I could learn about reading output from exec commands in my java program.
The above program runs successfully only after I add a Thread.sleep(2000) after it. I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry -- my recent expertise is on the shell side, not the Java side. You'll probably want to ask a separate question for that one. (As someone not particularly familiar with the API, it sounds like you're doing a non-blocking read but need a blocking one, if that helps).

Comment: No worries. Much much appreciated